# Using multiple addToSet does not work for multiple arrays in one operation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a document with the following fields:

```
    ...
    firebaseTokens: { type: Map, of: String },
    androidIds: [{ type: String, maxlength: 128 }],
    advertisingIds: [{ type: String, maxlength: 128 }],
    firebaseInstallationIds: [{ type: String, maxlength: 128 }],
    ...
```

When I want to set all three arrays using `$AddToSet` at the same time in one operation, only the last array is set.

```
 let user = {
     _id: userId,
     $set: { [`firebaseTokens.${deviceId}`]: token, },
     $addToSet: { androidIds: deviceId },
     $addToSet: { advertisingIds: advertisingId },
     $addToSet: { firebaseInstallationIds: firebaseInstallationId }
 }
 let options = { new: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true };
 let userDoc = await UserModel.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, user, options);
```

In the above code, only `firebaseInstallationIds` are set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you're encountering is due to the way the `$addToSet` operations are structured in your update object. In JavaScript, when you define an object with multiple properties having the same key, the last property overwrites all previous ones with the same key. This is why only `firebaseInstallationIds` is being set; it's the last `$addToSet` operation in your object.

To fix this, you need to combine all `$addToSet` operations into a single object.

Here is the working example:

```js
let user = {
    _id: userId,
    $set: { [`firebaseTokens.${deviceId}`]: token },
    $addToSet: {
        androidIds: deviceId,
        advertisingIds: advertisingId,
        firebaseInstallationIds: firebaseInstallationId
    }
}
let options = { new: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true };
let userDoc = await UserModel.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, user, options);
```